# Array Response Output

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm working on a little fun project that'll ask you a series of questions, and depending on what you respond with, give a specific output. Well, I've gotten all the way to the first output answer, but I can't figure out what to do.

Here's the source code. I can't seem to get the code input into the question correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questionaire {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   String answers[] = new String[1];
   String response[] = new String[5];

   System.out.println (" Good Evening, Devin. How are you today? "); 
   answers [0] = in.nextLine();




   response [0] = "I'm good";
   response [1] = "I'm okay";
   response [2] = "I'm alright";
   response [3] = "I'm great";
   response [4] = "good";

      if (answers[0].equals (response.length)) {
         System.out.println (" That's awesome! What would you like to talk about?" );
      }
      else {
         System.out.println( " Oh, well then.." );
      }
   }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Good Evening, Devin. How are you today? 
I'm okay
 Oh, well then..
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the if statement to take the whatever the user inputs into the answer[0] array, and if they respond with any of the responses in the response array, they get the first system.out, but whenever I type in any of them, I keep getting the else output. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please post the relevant code here.

Comment: Sorry, I just created my account not 30 minutes ago, so I'm still learning how to use everything :P Thanks for this assistance though. :D

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the match of the user input from `response` array.

`if (answers[0].equals (response.length))` will never evaluate to `true` unless the user input is `5` because you are comparing user input with `response.length` which value is `5`. You need to loop from each element in `response`

or simply change

```
if (answers[0].equals (response.length))
```

to

```
if(Arrays.asList(response).contains(answer[0]))
```

*you will need to add* `import java.util.Arrays`

Answer (score -1):

```
answers[0].equals (response.length)
```

This code will be false as answer[0] is string matching with response.length which is 5. if you want to check the answer with the response exist then code need to be modify as below

```
Boolean checkresponse=false;
for(int i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                  if (answers[0].equalsIgnoreCase(response[i])) {
                       System.out.println (" That's awesome! What would you like to talk   about?" );
                       checkresponse=true;
                       break;
                    }
              }
              if(checkresponse==false)
                  System.out.println( " Oh, well then.." );
```

Comment: don't you want to break or something?

Comment: what a mess.  Just break if true, why loop through the whole array when you have found what you are looking for